# BERT embeddings in LSTM model error in fit function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, bert-language-model

I am novice in TensorFlow

I am traying to use BERT embeddings in LSTM model
this is my model function

```
def bert_tweets_model():
    Bertmodel = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name,output_hidden_states=True)
    
    input_word_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_ids") 
    input_masks_in = tf.keras.Input(shape=(max_length,), name='masked_token', dtype='int32')
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        last_hidden_states = Bertmodel(input_word_ids, attention_mask=input_masks_in)[0]
        
    x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, dropout=0.1, activation='relu',recurrent_dropout=0.3,return_sequences = True)(last_hidden_states)
    x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, dropout=0.1,activation='relu', recurrent_dropout=0.3,return_sequences = True)(x)
    
    x=tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation='sigmoid')(x)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_word_ids, input_masks_in], outputs = output)
    
    return model

with strategy.scope():
    model = bert_tweets_model()
    adam_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=adam_optimizer,metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()


validation_data=[dev_encoded, y_val]
train2=[input_id, attention_mask]

history = model.fit(
    x=train2, y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=3,
    validation_data=validation_data,
    verbose=2)
```

I recieved this error in fit function when I tried to input data

"ValueError: Layer "model_1" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 512) dtype=int32>]"

also,I received these warning massages I do not know what is means.

WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_2 will not use cuDNN kernels since it doesn't meet the criteria. It will use a generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU.
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_3 will not use cuDNN kernels since it doesn't meet the criteria. It will use a generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU.

can someone help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regenerating your error**

```
_input1 = tf.random.uniform((1,100), 0 , 10)
_input2 = tf.random.uniform((1,100), 0 , 10)
model(_input1, _input2)
```

After running this code I am getting the same error...

```
Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 100), ...
```

```
#Now, the problem is you have to enclose the inputs in the set or list then you have to pass the inputs to the model like this

model((_input1, _input2))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.5324366, 0.3743334]], dtype=float32)>
```

**Remember:** if you are using `tf.data.Dataset` then encolse it then while making the dataset enclose the dataset within the set like this
`tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((words_id, words_mask))`

**Second Problem as you asked**

The warning you are getting because, you should be aware that LSTM doesn't run in *CUDA GPU* it uses the *CPU* only therefore it is slow, so *TensorFlow* is just telling you that LSTM will not run under GPU or parallel computing.